# Get IP address using uWebSockets

Tags: websocket

Please, how can I get sender IP address using uWebSockets?

```
const wss = new uws.Server({
  server: server,
  perMessageDeflate: false
});

wss.on(`connection`, ws => {
  ws.remoteAddress = ws.upgradeReq.connection.remoteAddress;
  console.log(`user connected: `, ws.remoteAddress);
});
```

user connected is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
wss.on(`connection`, ws => {
ws.remoteAddress = ws._socket.remoteAddress;
   console.log(`user connected: `, ws.remoteAddress);
});
```

You can also log `ws._socket` to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

ws._socket.remoteAddress should work , but if you ws server is behind a load balancer, you can get it via :

```
ws.upgradeReq.headers["x-forwarded-for"]
```